# Is Collections.sort() faster than Arrays.sort() in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

i was solving a codeforces problem [this one](https://codeforces.com/contest/1767/problem/B)
my first solution which uses a array got accepted while the contest was running but it got TLE on 7th testcases [the first code](https://codeforces.com/contest/1767/submission/185758316).
i tried to do the same with Arraylist which got accepted [second code](https://codeforces.com/contest/1767/submission/185598287)

below is the comparable code which is a function

```
static void solve(){
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        long arr[]=new long[n-1]   //ArrayList<Long> list=new ArrayList<>();
        long a=sc.nextLong();
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            arr[i]=list.add(sc.nextLong());
        }
        Array.sort(arr)            //Collections.sort(arrlist);
        for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            long b=arr[i];         //list.get(i);
            if(b>a){
                if((b-a)%2==1){
                    a+=((b-a)+1)/2;
                }else{
                    a+=(b-a)/2;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(a);

    }
```

Comment: `Arrays.sort(long[])` and `Collections.sort(Collection<Long>)` are *not* the same. `Collections.sort()` is *stable*, but `Arrays.sort()` is not.

Comment: The performance of the two sorts is something you can reasearch yourself, both by running them, and examining the implementations.